# How to fix build gradle asemble release failed in react native 0.59

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

I want to generate my project react native but i have some problems

Its in sdk version of my Android

```
>
> Configure project :react-native-vector-icons
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Could not list contents of '/Users/halojasa/halojasa_com/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
85 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 84 up-to-date
```

Now I can't release my App, please somebody help me . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines to `android/build.gradle` above allprojects code

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
allprojects {
 ...all project stuff...
}
```

Comment: can you explain more @AnkitDubey